# Extract sessions from events

Tags: clickhouse

In Clickhouse I have a table listing events with a user id and tag.
My aim is to extract sessions from this data.

A session is a group of events which time is close to each other. Let's say for the example that if an event is more than half an hour after the previous one it is in another session. A session can however be 12 hours long if there is an event every 15mn.

I looked at the documentation of the timeslot function, which describe a use case similar to mine, but I can't figure out how to write the query.
(https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/functions/date_time_functions/#timeslot)

For example:

Events:

```
date                | user  | tag
2018-12-21 00:00:00 │ user1 │ tag1
2018-12-21 00:00:00 │ user2 │ tag1
2018-12-21 00:15:00 │ user1 │ tag1
2018-12-21 00:15:00 │ user2 │ tag2
2018-12-21 00:30:00 │ user1 │ tag1
2018-12-21 00:45:00 │ user1 │ tag1
2018-12-21 01:45:00 │ user1 │ tag1
```

Resulting sessions:

```
date                | date_end            | user  | tag  | count
2018-12-21 00:00:00 | 2018-12-21 00:45:00 | user1 | tag1 | 4
2018-12-21 00:00:00 | 2018-12-21 00:00:00 | user2 | tag1 | 1
2018-12-21 00:15:00 | 2018-12-21 00:15:00 | user2 | tag2 | 1
2018-12-21 01:45:00 | 2018-12-21 01:45:00 | user1 | tag1 | 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query relies on default **timeSlot**-function that round down the date to the half hour:

```sql
SELECT user, tag, eventCount, length(sessionStartDateArray) sessionCount, sessionStartDateArray
FROM
(
    SELECT
        user,
        tag,
        -- a count of events with rounded date (remove DISTINCT-clause from nested query to get a real count of events).
        count() as eventCount,
        -- an array of rounded dates
        groupArray(roundedDate) AS roundedDateArray,
        -- an array of rounded dates shifted to 30 minutes (where 30 min taken from timeSlot-function)
        arrayMap(i -> (i + 1800), roundedDateArray) AS shiftedRoundedDateArray,
        -- to intersect two arrays to find the dates when sessions start
        arrayFilter(x -> (has(shiftedRoundedDateArray, x) = 0), roundedDateArray) AS sessionStartDateArray
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            user,
            tag,
            -- rounds down the time to the half hour.
            timeSlot(date) AS roundedDate
        FROM test01
    )
    GROUP BY user, tag
)
ORDER BY user, tag;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I am not used to working with arrays yet.
I just have a comment on the eventCount: if the DISTINCT is removed from the subquery, the groupArray has to be replaced by a groupUniqArray to avoid duplicates entries.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table C (D DateTime',' user String',' tag String) Engine = Memory;

insert into C values
('2018-12-21 00:00:00','user1','tag1'),
('2018-12-21 00:00:00','user2','tag1'),
('2018-12-21 00:15:00','user1','tag1'),
('2018-12-21 00:15:00','user2','tag2'),
('2018-12-21 00:30:00','user1','tag1'),
('2018-12-21 00:45:00','user1','tag1'),
('2018-12-21 01:45:00','user1','tag1'),



SELECT user, tag,
       toDateTime(((arrayJoin(arraySplit((k, j) -> j, Arr, 
              arrayMap(i -> i > 1800, 
              arrayDifference(arraySort(groupArray(toUnixTimestamp(D))) as Arr))))) 
              as R)[1]) b, 
       toDateTime(R[-1]) e,
       length(R) c
from C    
group by user, tag

┌─user──┬─tag──┬───────────────────b─┬───────────────────e─┬─c─┐
│ user2 │ tag2 │ 2018-12-21 00:15:00 │ 2018-12-21 00:15:00 │ 1 │
│ user1 │ tag1 │ 2018-12-21 00:00:00 │ 2018-12-21 00:45:00 │ 4 │
│ user1 │ tag1 │ 2018-12-21 01:45:00 │ 2018-12-21 01:45:00 │ 1 │
│ user2 │ tag1 │ 2018-12-21 00:00:00 │ 2018-12-21 00:00:00 │ 1 │
└───────┴──────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴───┘
```