# Count number of preceding repeating items in an array

Tags: clickhouse

I have the following query that goes through each item in an array and looks back to see how many repeating f's including itself came before.

It works however it will be slow across a large number of rows - is there a cleaner way to work with sequences within arrays?

```
SELECT
['p','p','f','f','f','f','p','f', 'f', 'f'] AS sequence,
arrayMap( (x,y) -> (x, 
   if (x='f', (arrayFirstIndex( k -> k=0,
       arrayCumSumNonNegative((n, index) -> n = 'f' ? 1 : -index,
       arrayReverse(arraySlice(sequence,1,y)) as arr,
       arrayEnumerate(arr)))
   )-1, 0)), sequence, arrayEnumerate(sequence))

result:

[('p',0),('p',0),('f',1),('f',2),('f',3),('f',4),('p',0),('f',1),('f',2),('f',3)]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: arrayDifference + arraySplit should solve it.

example https://stackoverflow.com/a/61617086/11644308

Or simply arraySplit(i -> i = 'p', sequence)

Comment: cheers denny again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```sql
WITH 'f' AS ch
SELECT　
  arraySplit((x, i) -> x = ch and sequence[i - 1] != ch or x != ch and sequence[i - 1] = ch, sequence, arrayEnumerate(sequence)) parts,
  arrayMap(part -> arrayMap((x, index) -> (x, x = ch ? index : 0), part, arrayEnumerate(part)), parts) parts_and_number,
  arrayFlatten(parts_and_number) result
FROM (
  SELECT arrayJoin([
    ['p','p','f','f','f','f','p','f', 'f', 'f'],
    ['p','w','f','f','f','f','p','f', 'f', 'f'],
    ['f','f','f','f','p','f', 'f', 'f'],
    ['p','w'],
    ['f', 'f'],  
    ['f']
  ]) as sequence)

/*
Row 1:
──────
parts:            [['p','p'],['f','f','f','f'],['p'],['f','f','f']]
parts_and_number: [[('p',0),('p',0)],[('f',1),('f',2),('f',3),('f',4)],[('p',0)],[('f',1),('f',2),('f',3)]]
result:           [('p',0),('p',0),('f',1),('f',2),('f',3),('f',4),('p',0),('f',1),('f',2),('f',3)]

Row 2:
──────
parts:            [['p','w'],['f','f','f','f'],['p'],['f','f','f']]
parts_and_number: [[('p',0),('w',0)],[('f',1),('f',2),('f',3),('f',4)],[('p',0)],[('f',1),('f',2),('f',3)]]
result:           [('p',0),('w',0),('f',1),('f',2),('f',3),('f',4),('p',0),('f',1),('f',2),('f',3)]

Row 3:
──────
parts:            [['f','f','f','f'],['p'],['f','f','f']]
parts_and_number: [[('f',1),('f',2),('f',3),('f',4)],[('p',0)],[('f',1),('f',2),('f',3)]]
result:           [('f',1),('f',2),('f',3),('f',4),('p',0),('f',1),('f',2),('f',3)]

Row 4:
──────
parts:            [['p','w']]
parts_and_number: [[('p',0),('w',0)]]
result:           [('p',0),('w',0)]

Row 5:
──────
parts:            [['f','f']]
parts_and_number: [[('f',1),('f',2)]]
result:           [('f',1),('f',2)]

Row 6:
──────
parts:            [['f']]
parts_and_number: [[('f',1)]]
result:           [('f',1)]
*/
```

Comment: @redsquare np, I glad to help you